# permalink changed, now getting 404 for every pages

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

i have my website with permalink,
till now everything was fine, but few days before i changed my permalink, now everything is going wrong,
now each and every page i am getting 404,
even my about-us and contact us pages, they are giving me 404 page
if i come to my site from google or any search engines, then also it gives me 404
i have 1000+ posts on my website, for each post & page from google i get 404 page, but within the website except pages i get no 404 page

**my previous permalink:**
`%postname%/%category%/`

now i added custom taxonomy to my permalink,
**so now it is:**`%location%/%courses%/%postname%`

I asked this question first also, but it was into wrong section i guess, thats why asking again and in detail.

**Related Question:** [custom taxonomies on permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6071/custom-taxonomies-on-permalink)

Comment: Where did you first ask that question? Please give link.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6071/custom-taxonomies-on-permalink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-permalinks/ check this plugin, I've used it on a couple of sites and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I might be very wrong on this one, but I don't think that you can add things like %location% or %courses% to your permalink structure. At least not out of nothing. So at least it looks like information about your configuration is missing to answer your question.

Comment: no you can add, thats the custom-taxonomy, you add that to the permalink, and it works also, because of that i am not getting 404, if i put postname in start then everything works fine

Comment: I then assume that your custom permalink structure is incompatible with wordpress. You should probably introduce some numeric ID with a seperator char in there to make it compatible.

Comment: custom-taxanomies are working perfect in permalink, if i remove postname or move it to the start, then also website functions properly

Comment: Yes, but if you don't want to do that, you might be able to gain compatibility by adding some numerical value as a hint for the permalink resolver. That's all I meant. If you found your solution and my answer helped you in doing so, please rate it and mark it as answer.

Comment: what numerical value to attach? and where?

Comment: Probably something like `/%location%/%courses%/%postname%/%post_id%` is doing the job. It adds the post id at the end, probably WP is clever enough to focus on the numeric ID first. The only thing I ask myself is, what does happen if some post does not have any location? But that's probably not the problem for you site.

Comment: i tried this `/%location%/%courses%/%postname%/%post_id%` but still getting 404,
if i use this permalink
`/%postname%/%location%/%courses%/` is it possible that post-name should not be displayed? the url should start with location

Comment: i just found some similar thing over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696776/htaccess-question-can-i-strip-out-a-leading-question-mark just need to strip the starting in my query